# How can I restrict the type of data my users enter at the class level

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Reference : AuditableTable
{
     [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
     [DisplayName("Order")]
     public int Order { get; set; 
}
```

With MVC the Range check should stop the user entering bad data. However my other code that does not go through the MVC front end allows me to enter in values like 999. Is it normal to have checking at the class level for this and how could I implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate field on client side, then you should use validators. In case of server validation, this code should work. I'm talking about asp.net MVC.

Comment: I am not sure any more. When I look at my table I can see a value of 400 that I just inserted.

Comment: I'm talking about MVVC model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
private bool ValidateModel(dynamic model)
{
   var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
   var ctx = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
   return Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ctx, validationResults, true);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx

Instead of dynamic you can place any model type.

Comment: I will look at the link now. So are you saying that the validation I have will not work at the server level as is without any additional checks?

Comment: If you are using this object as MVC model and you have strongly typed views and controllers this method will be internally called when controller binds the model, otherwise you shall validate model manually.

I use this function to validate models objects in my unit tests, also it can be used when some of your mvc application objects are used by another non-mvc application

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Reference : AuditableTable
    {
        [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
        [DisplayName("Order")]
        public int Range { get; 
        set { 
       if((value < 0) || (value > 99))
        {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} must be between 0 and 99",value.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
        Range = value;
        }
        }
    }
```